# Calling fopen on Windows core files returns NULL pointer

Tags: c, windows, fopen

I am trying to open a couple different files via their absolute path (determined elsewhere, programmatically), so I can get their SHA1 hash*, some of which are core windows files. fopen() is returning NULL on some (but not all) files when I attempt to open them as follows (normally the filename is gotten via QueryFullProcessImageName but I hardcoded it just in case):

```
char * filename = "c:\\windows\\system32\\spoolsv.exe";
FILE * currFileRead = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (currFileRead == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open %s, error %s\n", filename, strerror(errno) );
}
else
{
    //hashing code
}
```

The reported error is 2: "No such file or directory", but obviously they're there. It also only fails for some processes, like spoolsv.exe or winlogon.exe, while svchost.exe and wininint.exe seem to open just fine.

My program has administrative privileges, and I can't figure why some processes would fail while others opened without trouble?

*I'm using a method from LibTomCrypt (http://libtom.org/?page=features) which is open source with a permissive license. The call to sha1_process takes in a hash_state (internal to the library), an unsigned char buffer, and the length of the buffer. I need to read the file with fopen to get the file into memory for hashing.

Comment: Would like to see what GetLastError() says. Could you use GetLastError() and FormatMessage() (or manual lookup)?

Comment: Change it to sysnative instead of system32 on a 64-bit operating system.  Or build a 64-bit program so file redirection doesn't byte.  Fwiw, computing a hash on a file that is likely to be updated by Windows Update is probably not wise.

Comment: RonBurk GetLastError is also reporting 2, which (per MSDN) is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - i.e. the same problem.
HansPassant - My program needs to run on both 32 and 64 bit hosts. So  I can't just make a 64 bit version. What do you mean changing it to sysnative?

Comment: You are being caught out by the file system redirector. Google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your program is a 32-bit process, when you try to open `c:\windows\system32` you actually get `c:\windows\syswow64` which does not contain all of the same files.

You can use [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine whether you are running on a 64-bit system.  If you are, you can replace `system32` with `sysnative` in the path to open the actual file, unless you need to support Windows 2003 or Windows XP.  Depending on your circumstances, you might need to cope with the possibility that the Windows folder is not `c:\windows` and/or the possibility that there are other folders named `system32`.

On the whole it would be more robust to have separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your application, or perhaps just the particular part of it that is exhibiting the problem.  If you can't leave it up to the user to install the appropriate version, the installer could decide which to install, or you could always install both and have the 32-bit version automatically launch the 64-bit version when running on a 64-bit system.

Comment: This was the solution (Hans Passant gave me enough to move in this direction, though IsWow64Process is something I hadn't found).

Given issues I'm having with EnumProcessModules between 32 and 64-bit binaries, I am going to commit to writing two separate binaries.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Having administrative privileges is not always enough, because if the file you want to open is in use and the program that is using it has locked it, then you can't open and read that file.

Comment: So, my understanding is that I should be able to open it for reading in just about all cases. I can open one of these .exe files in, say, notepad, for example (though obviously the result is garbage) without any issue. I just can't seem to open it in c.